# updating the deployment, need to change multiple values

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I am trying to automate the update to the deployment using

```
kubectl set
```

I have no issues using kubectl set image command to push new version of the docker image out, but I also need to add a new persistent disk for the new image to use. I don't believe i can set 2 different options using the set command. What would be the best option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/managing-deployments/#in-place-updates-of-resources has the different options you have.

---

You can use [`kubectl apply`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_apply/) to modify multiple fields at once.

> Apply a configuration to a resource by filename or stdin. This
>   resource will be created if it doesn’t exist yet. To use ‘apply’,
>   always create the resource initially with either ‘apply’ or ‘create
>   –save-config’. JSON and YAML formats are accepted.

Alternately, one can use [`kubectl patch`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/).

> Update field(s) of a resource using strategic merge patch JSON and
>   YAML formats are accepted.

Comment: Thank you, i did create the deployment initially with the create -f name.yaml where the kind was set to deployment. now however, i need to edit the deployment in a similar manner as described [here](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment). So according to what you are saying, I can modify the file i used to create the original deployment with what I need and then use apply to roll out the changes?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Another option is to use http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/. It seems like the latter may be more appropriate for your use.